# How far can we rearrange terms of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let $ \{x_{n}\} $ be a sequence of real numbers. Let $ S $ be the set of all subsequential limits of $ \{x_{n}\} $. (Considering the possibility that even $ \pm\infty $ may belong to $ S $). Let $ \varphi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} $ be a permutation on $ \mathbb{N} $. What can we say about the set of all subsequential limits of the rearranged sequence $ \{x_{\varphi(n)}\} $?

I know that $ S $ will remain invariant if it is a singleton. (i.e., $ \{x_{n}\} $ is either convergent, or diverging to $ \infty $ or $ -\infty $). However, I am confused about a general case for $ S $. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I came up with the following argument:

> Let $ c\in S $ be a finite real number. Let $ \mathbb{N}_{1} $ be the
> subset of $ \mathbb{N} $, arranged in natural order, so that the
> subsequence $ \{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{1}} $ converges to $ c $. Fix
> $ \epsilon>0 $ arbitrary. Let for $ k_{1}\in \mathbb{N}_{1} $, $
>  \lvert x_{n}-c\rvert<\epsilon $ holds for every $ n\in\mathbb{N}_{1} $
> and $ n\ge k_{1} $. Call $$ k_{2}=\max\{\varphi^{-1}(n):n\in\mathbb{N}_{1},n\le k_{1}\}. $$ Then
> for each $ n\ge k_{2} $ from $ \mathbb{N}_{1} $, $ \varphi(n)\ge k_{1} $. Therefore $ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{1} $, and $ n\ge k_{2} $, $ \lvert x_{\varphi(n)}-c\rvert <\epsilon $. Consequently, the
> rearranged sequence $ \{x_{\varphi(n)}\} $ converges to $ c $ as well.
> Similar arguments hold when $ c=\pm\infty $.
>
> Thus, if $ S' $ be the set of all subsequential limits of $ \{x_{\varphi(n)}\} $, then $ S\subset S' $. Similarly, considering $ \{x_{n}\} $ as a rearranged sequence from $ \{x_{\varphi(n)}\} $ via
> the inverse permutation $ \varphi^{-1}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} $, we
> can conclude that $ S'\subset S $ as well. Hence $ S=S' $.

Please comment on this argument.

Answer (score 1):

$S$ always stays the same.

Suppose that $s \in S$. We have subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which converges to $s$.
For any permutation $\varphi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, notice that we can choose $m_l$ such that $m_l$ is increasing and $m_l = \varphi(n_{k_l})$ for some increasing $k_l$. We could for example choose $m_1 =\varphi(n_{1})$ and $k_1 = 1$, and whenever $m_l$ and $k_l$  were already chosen, choose $k_{l+1}$ to be smallest number bigger thatn $k_l$ for which $\varphi(n_{k_{l+1}}) > \varphi(n_{k_{l}})$, and then put $m_{l+1} = \varphi(n_{k_{l+1}})$.

Now $x_{m_l}$ is subsequence of $ x_{\varphi(n)} $ as well as subsequence of $x_{n_k}$. So it is subsequence of permutation that converges to $s$.

Conversely, if $s$ was the limit of some subsequence of $ x_{\varphi(n)} $, we can use the result above for sequence $  x'_n :=x_{\varphi(n)}$ and permutation $\varphi':= \varphi^{-1}$ to obtain that $s\in S$.

Comment: Sorry for my inability to follow the construction of the indices. In the meantime, I came up with some arguments posted in the Edit. Would like to have your comments on that.

Comment: @Subhajit Paul: I'm not trying to follow all the notation and subscripts either, but I think the issue is nothing more than the fact that the **set** of subsequences is not changed by a permutation, which seems fairly straightforward to me (a permutation is a bijective "relabeling" of the subscripts), unless I'm overlooking something. And if the **set** of subsequences is not changed, then it follows that the set of subsequent limits is also not changed.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I think the whole objective of that rigorous construction is to create an increasing sequence of indices. This is the part I cannot see intuitively for a general permutation. I get the idea of the relabelling part, which as you mentioned, is fairly straightforward. Please have a look on my Edit portion and comment.

Comment: @Subhajit Paul: It seems you've identified something that is included in "unless I'm missing something". The increasing sequence of indices aspect can probably be taken care of by using the fact that for each neighborhood of the limit of the original (pre-permutation) subsequence there exists infinitely many tails of that subsequence, each tail of which has at least one term within that neighborhood, and so there exists at least one (in fact, infinitely many I think) tail of the permutated subsequence that has a term within that neighborhood, or something along these lines.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Correct! That will be a much simpler and rigorous line of construction at the same time. Thanks!